# How to solve this build gradle new version issue in my project

Tags: java, android

**hello**, **how i can solve this issue in my project**:

i need to change this version: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'   into this new one: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath "io.github.porum:muddy-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**but when i change it,in building i'm getting this issue and building fail**:

Unable to find method ''void com.android.build.api.variant.ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtension.registerSourceType(java.lang.String)''
'void com.android.build.api.variant.ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtension.registerSourceType(java.lang.String)'

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

**I need help to solve this issue, is causing me to not be able to integrate firebase messaging in my project**

Comment: Please use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code, errors and logs.